# c++ why is it valid to dereference a shared_ptr to a const type to a non-const variable?

Tags: const-correctness

Why is the following legal?

```
std::shared_ptr<const Foo> foo = std::make_shared(new Foo());
Foo bar = *foo;
```

shouldn't it be only legal to dereference to `const Foo`?

Answer (score 1):

Because assigning as you have invokes the copy constructor, and the newly created variable will not affect the original one. this is the same as

```
const int x = 3
int y = x;
```

`x` is copied to `y`, and there is no problem with that. This however, is illegal:

```
Foo *bar = foo;
```

or this

```
Foo &bar = *foo;
```

Of course, the compiler only checks this in a "shallow" manner, so you can definitely FooBar yourself. It would be too hard to demand compilers to do anything better. An example with a memory leak (the leak is not the point, I'm just lazy):

```
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>

struct Foo {
     int *x;
     Foo(int x) : x(new int(x)) {}
 };

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<const Foo> foo = std::make_shared<Foo>(3);
    Foo bar = *foo;
    *bar.x = 5;
    std::cout<<*foo->x<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The output is 5... This type of bugs sucks, and makes stuff like rules of 3 (5 etc) and const correctness (in all your code) important. In fact, you do not even have to try that hard. This "breaks" too:

```
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>

struct Foo {
     int *x;
     Foo(int x) : x(new int(x)) {}
 };

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<const Foo> foo = std::make_shared<Foo>(3);
    *foo.x = 5;
    std::cout<<*foo->x<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This behavior is not special to C++. Off the top of my head, tuples containing lists in Python are another example of something that are often expected to be const but can be changed.

I guess you could call this "shallow constness", and as such, is expected behavior, and not really a bug though often the cause of them - `const` **guarantees the object, not anything contained in it** (if it is a container, contained meaning on a level more "inner" than the fields of the object). Some containers may provide additional guarantees, but that has to be implemented.

Comment: but const Foo also means I can't call non-const Functions on it, while I'm able to call non-const functions after the assignment

Comment: @user1282931 I don't understand your point. In your example, `bar` is a whole new copy of the original `foo`. What does it matter what methods it calls?

Comment: @user1282931 Unless you have a faulty copy constructor and dynamic memory allocation? That could be a problem, and the compiler won't find that.

Comment: what if Foo stores internal pointers to other objects? they will be shared and while const functions can't change these internal objects (by calling non-const functions on them) a non-const function can and will change the underlying internal object. I know I'm likely wrong but that's where my confusion is coming from

Comment: @user1282931 Check updated answer. Compilers can't handle non-shallow const checks. In short, if you do not code safely, you're screwed.

Comment: @user1282931 Just realized there is even a better example... see answer.